# How can i write to a txt file several variables from servlet?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, permission-denied, writetofile

I have a web form page (jsp) ,where user gives some variables.
I have a java class which has the same names.So with jsp bean i pass the user's input into 2 variables.
So i have var_1=greek,var_2=turkey.

I want now to pass these variables to a properties.txt file with a servlet.The problem is that it gives me this error:

/properties.txt (Permission denied)

to make the servlet i followed this example:[WriteToFileServlet](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/9798-Writing-a-file-using-servlets.html)

How i can write to a file, my variables??

Comment: permission denied just means that the servlet is trying to write to a place where it's not authorized to write. Choose a directory that is writable by the OS user under which the servlet container runs.

Comment: "/properties.txt"  is the path you are writing to. Or is it relative to the application content directory.

Comment: It is relative to the application content directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try writing to the file which is relative to the application content directory.

```
String path = servletContext.getRealPatch("/tmp/properties.txt");
//write to path
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change permission to your server directory that it would be writable. Linux command: `chmod 777 dirName` provides full permissions to that directory.

If you want all folders and files in specific directory to be writable too, you have to run this command: `chmod 777 -R dirName`.

To get more info about permissions you should read this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/linux-file-and-directory-permissions/1047531